# Returning a Generic list from JsonNode using an Object Mapper?

Tags: java, json, list, generics, objectmapper

I have the following code that returns a `list` of `strings` from a `JsonNode`:

```
   public static List<String> asList(final JsonNode jsonNode) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, ArrayList.class);
    }
```

**Example usage:**

```
 List<String> identities = Utils.asList(jsonNode);
```

I want to change this to use `Generics` to ensure that a `JsonNode` contain a list of any Type can also be converted and returned.

I have the below implementation (not uses Jackson `ObjectMapper`), but is this the optimal solution?

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(final JsonNode jsonNode) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, ArrayList.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a util method that accepts `JSON` string and `TypeReference`

```
public <T> T jsonMapper(String json, TypeReference<T> typeReference)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
}
```

For example you can call this method either to convert json string to `List` or single `Object`

```
List<String> lOfStr = jsonMapper(json,new TypeReference<List<String>>() { });
Employee emp = jsonMapper(json,new TypeReference<Employee>() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unchecked assignment you can use [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(final JsonNode jsonNode) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});
}
```